# Cannot execute SQL Query dbo.sysmergepublications with eror Invalid object name

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I have the following SQL query:

```
 create view  [dbo].[v_ds_phanmanh] as
SELECT  PUBS.description AS COSO, SUBS.subscriber_server AS TENSERVER
FROM  dbo.sysmergepublications AS PUBS INNER JOIN
      dbo.sysmergesubscriptions AS SUBS ON PUBS.pubid = SUBS.pubid
      AND PUBS.publisher <> SUBS.subscriber_server
GO
```

But when I execute, I got this error message:
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure v_ds_phanmanh, Line 3 [Batch Start Line 236]
Invalid object name 'dbo.sysmergepublications'.
 I've tried Google this problem and follow the solutions but it doesn't work. Can someone help me on this problem?
Thanks
The full query: [Ghostbin](https://ghostbin.co/paste/5tmh5)

Comment: Are you able to run the query SELECT * FROM dbo.sysmergepublications?

Comment: Do you have any Merge Replication publications in the database?